# Can Rogue harness Wolverine's adamantium blades after touching him?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, rogue

Rogue has the ability to harness the abilities of other mutants for a short while upon any sort of skin contact. Upon touching Wolverine she is able to use his regenerative properties but what about his blades? Adamantium is experimentally deployed in Wolverine's bones so would she able to harness that power too or instead Wolverine's old bone claws would come out of her hands?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Rogue does get Wolverine's claws when she absorbs his abilities, but she gets his original bone claws, without the adamantium. The bone claws can be seen in [X-Men Legacy #235](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men:_Legacy_Vol_1_235) (2010), when Rogue absorbs the abilities of several X-Men.

[image: Rogue - X-Men Legacy 235]

Comment: Bone claws through Colossus' metal skin, I wonder how that works.

Comment: @S.Albano Magic...I'm sure ONE of the X-Men she's absorbed here has magic in their abilities somewhere.

Comment: Looks like she has some [X-23](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-23) going on there too with the toe claw as well.

Comment: I would have guessed the answer was "No", with her only getting his healing factor & senses, but obviously this proves me wrong. Good answer!

Answer (score 11):

No.

Rogue can harness abilities of only living things. She can't just absorb strength of a rock like Kevin (of Ben 10).

As Adamantium implant isn't biological ability of Wolverine, it can't be harnessed by her.

Comment: What has Ben-10 got to do with X-Men? Surely The Thing or another Marvel in-universe comparison would be better.

Answer (score 6):

There've been a change in Wolverine a few years back.

On the origin, the character hasn't natural claws, they were deployed to him with the adamantium on his skeleton, but his only natural powers where his animal instincts and senses and his overwhelming regeneration power.

I remember perfectly a comic (more than 20 years ago) where Rogue touched Wolverine and got his regeneration and senses, but not the claws.

However... at some point in time (that I don't know exactly because I stopped reading comics for several years) there was a change in the Wolverine origins resemble, and from this point the claws where part of his original powers, although they were bone claws, quite fragile and prone to break (and regenerate) until adamantium covering came to the rescue.

From that point and on, as their bone claws were part of their original powers, they can be replicated by characters like Rogue.

Comment: If I rememebr correctly, this change happened mid-90s. There was  storyline where Magneto pulled all of the adamantium out of Wolverine. The trauma of that event led Wolverine to revert to a animalistic, feral state. At this point, everyone (in and out of universe) was surprised that he healed with bone claws. (The obvious out of universe reason is that you can't let a popular character like Wolverine go without his signature feature for long enough to write a good storyline.)

Comment: @Pursuit I remember everyone at the time speculating that when Magneto pulled the adamantium out of his skeleton, Wolverine "healed" the loss of his claws by replacing them with bone. Of course we found out later when Wolverine's true origin was finally revealed that the bone claws were a part of his original mutation, but I thought it was an interesting theory at the time.

Comment: However we know this was an "ad hoc" idea through the history of the character, as if it had the claws from the very beginning, Rogue could have used the bone claws in it's first "encounters" with Wolverine. Also, I recall old comics where Logan origins are depict and he always fought barehanded, even against Sabretooth

Answer (score -2):

No. Simply because adamantium is a material where as bone it is a material but everybody is born with bone in their body. If he was born with adamantium then most likely yes but because it is a gene alteration then no. If she absorbed wolverines powers popped the bone claws and absorbed colosses then she might be able to coat the bone claws coated in whatever metal colosseum is made out of but it wouldn't be adamantium

Comment: This doesn't really address the question and contains a lot of equivocation rather than a solid answer.

Answer (score -2):

In the extreme X-Men comic she had his bone claws and then again during the Messiah complex where she took everyone's powers Colossus Nightcrawler Wolverine angel psylocke

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This doesn't actually add much to the accepted answer; perhaps you could include the specific issue number and possibly some images.

Answer (score -4):

Someone mentioned Rogue can't absorb strength of a rock from Ben 10. Except Rogue has absorbed Ben Grimm's abilities as the Thing. She also was able to absorb Colossus' ability to turn in to Omnium. But I can't remember if that happened in his armored form or not.

So I question the non organic part of that claim. Granted, Colossus' omnium skin is considered an organic steel, but still.

There was a story line where Colossus was super heated, and then super cooled, and he froze in his armor form. And Rogue touched him to absorb his powers, IIRC, in the hopes to take his power from him and revert him back to human form (when she steals powers from people, they are unable to use them for a short time, due to being weakened IIRC).

But again, since Colossus' omnium steel is considered living organic steel, that may be why she was able to do that in his metallic form, even though he was frozen in his metal form.